# Asymptote for double variable function

Tags: asymptotics

How can I find asymptote of the following function ?

$y=x^{3}y^{2} - \sin(x)$

Is there a way except finding $y$ directly ?

Comment: Intuitively, if $x$ is very large, $y$ has to be very small to make $y-y^2x^3=\sin x$.

Comment: Ever heard of quadratic equations?

Comment: Here's a plot for $(x,y) \in (-20,20) \times (-1,1)$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrMLW.png

Comment: @ Ivan Neretin: ys i know.. i can calculate y in terms of x but i want to know if i can find the asymptote without finding y.